# GeckoDriver in PATH, but getting Selenium Webdriver Error

Tags: ruby, path, webdriver

I needed to reinstall Ruby 2.3.3. I'm getting selenium webdriver error now though, which I've had before, but all I needed to do was add my geckodriver to path. As you can see in the screenshot below, my geckodriver path is correct.

My terminal output

```
C:\development>ruby test.rb
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:114:in `create_session': no sessionId in returned payload (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:70:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/w3c_bridge.rb:35:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:87:in `for'
        from test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Path Image
[image]

I have tried redownloading and installing geckodriver, deleting the old path and adding the new one, restarting after that and also tried creating a new web test. The result is the same everytime. All the gems I need for this to work are installed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of using  gem install selenium-webdriver -v 3.2.1, I needed to use gem install selenium-webdriver